# Nested condition is not working in Vtiger Rest Query API

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I'm trying to work with Query API to get matched results set from Vtiger.

This API works fine with normal queries (without multiple AND/ OR conditions) like:
working_query = `SELECT * FROM Leads WHERE id = 10x2482688 AND designation = 'SalesMan' order by createdtime LIMIT 1;`

But we want to get results using nested AND/OR and those will contain parentheses. ")"
and we are getting errors like `'QUERY_SYNTAX_ERROR', Syntax Error on line 1: token '(' Unexpected`

Not_working_query = `SELECT * FROM Leads WHERE id = 10x2482688 AND (email = 'test@yahoo.com' OR designation = 'SalesMan') order by createdtime LIMIT 1;`

Any ideas on how we can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your query to

```
SELECT * FROM Leads WHERE id = '10x2482688' AND email = 'test@yahoo.com' OR id = '10x2482688' and designation = 'SalesMan' order by createdtime LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's useful but in the case of multi-level nesting, this solution will create more complexity, and also I can see performance for such operations is not quite good. API will take a much longer time to get executed.